error when deploying in railway react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build react-scripts: Permission denied
I have a project deployed in railway. but, after uploading some changes to my git repository, railway cannot deploy it, I have not had this problem before.error when deploying in railway this is the log
context: e2108f3aa32b2e84b9f98fb2c54eeb60
╔════════ Nixpacks v1.21.2 ═══════╗
║ setup      │ nodejs_18, npm-9_x ║
║─────────────────────────────────║
║ install    │ npm ci             ║
║─────────────────────────────────║
║ build      │ npm run build      ║
║─────────────────────────────────║
║ start      │ npm start          ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╝
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 2.42kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s
#2 [internal] load metadata for ghcr.io/railwayapp/nixpacks:ubuntu-1707782610
#2 DONE 0.1s
#3 [stage-0  1/10] FROM ghcr.io/railwayapp/nixpacks:ubuntu-1707782610@sha256:8f4b0fd95dc3311cf9a59f236d8d7d7f956fe21a2a1d64b53c82f12c4e859f09
#3 DONE 0.0s
#4 [stage-0  2/10] WORKDIR /app/
#4 CACHED
#5 [internal] load .dockerignore
#5 transferring context: 2B done
#5 DONE 0.0s
#6 [internal] load build context
#6 transferring context: 89.38MB 5.1s
#6 transferring context: 210.77MB 10.3s
#6 transferring context: 325.02MB 15.8s
#6 transferring context: 325.02MB 15.8s done
#6 DONE 16.0s
#7 [stage-0  3/10] COPY .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix
#7 CACHED
#8 [stage-0  4/10] RUN nix-env -if .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix && nix-collect-garbage -d
#8 CACHED
#9 [stage-0  5/10] COPY . /app/.
#9 DONE 16.8s
#10 [stage-0  6/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/714292d9-751e-4ad7-beeb-0d65a1b6535b-/root/npm,target=/root/.npm npm ci
#10 1.348 npm
WARN config production Use --omit=dev instead.
#10 17.29 npm
WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
#10 18.01 npm
WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
#10 19.11 npm
WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
#10 19.38 npm WARN
deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
You reached the start of the range → May 17, 2024 5:22 PM
#10 20.54 npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
#10 22.30 npm WARN deprecated
svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
#10 40.76
#10 40.76 added 1861 packages, and audited 1862 packages in 39s
#10 40.76
#10 40.76 282 packages are looking for funding
#10 40.76   run npm fund for details
#10 40.78
#10 40.78 8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)
#10 40.78
#10 40.78 To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
#10 40.78   npm audit fix --force
#10 40.78
#10 40.78 Run npm audit for details.
#10 DONE 41.3s
#11 [stage-0  7/10] COPY . /app/.
#11 DONE 16.1s
#12 [stage-0  8/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/714292d9-751e-4ad7-beeb-0d65a1b6535b-node_modules/cache,target=/app/node_modules/.cache npm run build
#12 1.025 npm
WARN config production Use --omit=dev instead.
#12 1.138
#12 1.138 > capacitaciones-farmasis@0.1.0 build
#12 1.138 > react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build
#12 1.138
#12 1.146 sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied
#12 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 126


[stage-0  8/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/714292d9-751e-4ad7-beeb-0d65a1b6535b-node_modules/cache,target=/app/node_modules/.cache npm run build:

WARN config production Use --omit=dev instead.
1.138
1.138 > capacitaciones-farmasis@0.1.0 build
1.138 > react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build
1.138
1.146 sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied

Dockerfile:24

22 |     # build phase
23 |     COPY . /app/.
24 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/714292d9-751e-4ad7-beeb-0d65a1b6535b-node_modules/cache,target=/app/node_modules/.cache npm run build
25 |
26 |

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 126
Error: Docker build failed
Log Explorer | Railway
npm install -g svgo
npm i @rollup/plugin-terser
npm i @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec
npm i
npm install react-scripts@latest
npm install -g react-scripts
npm install react-scripts --dev
